# Understanding action of $(\mathbb Z_p/(p^n))^ \times$ in Lubin Tate formal group laws context on $\mathbb{Q}_p[\zeta_{p^r}]$

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, class-field-theory, cyclotomic-fields

I want to understand that the isomorphism
$$(\mathbb Z_p/(p^n))^\times\ \stackrel{\sim}{\longrightarrow}\ \text{Gal}(\mathbb Q_p[\zeta_{p^r}]/\mathbb Q_p),$$
is the standard one.

So how does element $a\in(\mathbb Z_p/(p^n))^ \times $ act on $x \in \mathbb Q_p[\zeta_{p^r}]$? By Lubin-Tate formal group laws description it acts as $[a]_f(x) $, so for example on $\zeta_{p^r}$ as $[a]_f(\zeta_{p^r}) $. We come back to this but first we figure how $a$ acts via standard isomorphism.

I suppose it does as $a\cdot\zeta_{p^r}=\zeta_{p^r}^{a} $ (note that $(a,n)=1$).

So back to $[a]_f $ it is $[a]_f=aT+(\text{deg} \geq 2) $ and $[a]_f \circ f=f \circ [a]_f $. We had started with $f(T)=(1+T)^p-1$.

I do not see how these two actions will be same?

Comment: Can you convince yourself that $[a]_f(T) = (1 + T)^a - 1 = aT + \binom{a}{2}T^2 + \cdots$?  The right side is in $\mathbf Z_p[[T]]$ since $\binom{a}{n} \in \mathbf Z_p$ for all $n \geq 0$.  Also, you should be acting in the formal group not on $\zeta_{p^r}$, but on $\zeta_{p^r} - 1$: those differences are in the maximal ideal, which is where the power series in the formal group are evaluated.

Comment: @KCd Yes, thanks for your comment. So how does $a$ act on an element in  $\mathcal O_K^ \times \backslash 1+ \mathfrak m $ ? Via the polynomial of $[a]_f$?

Comment: What is your reference on Lubin-Tate theory? It should  explain how a field automorphism is determined by its values on the open unit disc.

Comment: @KCd Milne's notes on class field theory.

Comment: See the last sentence of the proof of Theorem 1.13 and the last sentence of the proof of 1.14. The definition of the local Artin map on p. 40 tells you how $K^\times$ acts using Frobenius and the action on torsion points.  (My initial comment above, by the way, is in Example 2.18.)